How to use 'String.Equals' in Handlebars.Net.Helpers
I am trying to use the String.Equals helper of Handlebars.Net but it seems there is not even one example in the github repo on how to do that.
Can anyone help me please? How should my template look like if I want to check for instance if a value (from the data) is equal to a specific string (literal)?

You can use the String.Equal helper method from the package Handlebars.Net.Helpers.
For more details on how to use, see: StringHelpersTemplateTests.cs
